# Problem displaying Hebrew characters in VS debugger with char/CString

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2019, hebrew

I am having trouble with displaying Hebrew characters in Visual Studio.

In my app, they are printed right and well, but in Visual Studio while debugging, I get this:

[image: Weird text]

I have to mention that I am using codepage 1255, I can't use Unicode because my source is big and it would take years to convert.

Comment: Visual Studio's debugger probably is unaware that you are using codepage 1255.  Is Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings > Language set appropriately?

Comment: If the text is encoded as utf-8, and the data is stored in an array of `char` or a default `std::string`, it'll use the current locale instead of utf-8 for debugging display. You can cast the data to a `const char8_t*` (even directly in the watch window) to be explicit about the encoding.

Comment: @YarinLevy An image is sometimes worth a thousand words: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MrQE.png. Notice how adding `(const char8_t*)` in front of `b` in the watch window magically fixes the issue.

Comment: "I get <Invalid characters in string>" -- thi is probably because your source code is not encoded as UTF-8 and/or is not compiled with /utf-8 switch.

Comment: I tried using the /utf-8 switch, it didn't help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing wrong. It simply works out of the box. Start VS, create a new console project, add some strings in any language, watch them in the debugger window. Literally no fiddling whatsoever with anything at all.